# Counting number of zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

How many zeroes does the polynomial $z^{2015} + 8z^{12} + 1$ have in the region $re(z)>0,im(z)>0$ ? I'm seeing no way of using Rouche's theorem, please help someone

Comment: Consider the argument principle

Comment: $z^{2003}+8=0$ has $501$ roots in the first quadrant, $z^{12}+\frac18=0$ has $3$ roots in the first quadrant, if that stays stable under the perturbation from $(z^{2003}+8)(z^{12}+\frac18)=z^{2015}+\frac18z^{2003}+8z^{12}+1$ to the given polynomial, this makes $504$ roots in this quadrant.